# section title in \frametitle beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, titles

I want to create a new environment, based on the frame environment, but I want to modify the command `\frametitle` so it also shows the title of the current section.

Comment: That's no bigger problem however knowing which theme you are using would make things much easier. So maybe you could provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be much easier if you can simply put a simple MWE. It's only six lines of code anyway. So here is my guess.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newenvironment{slide}[1]
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide]
\frametitle{\insertsection-#1}}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\section{Sec shun 1}
\frame{Dummy frames}
\begin{slide}{My title 1}
Some stufff
\end{slide}


\section{Sec shun 2}
\begin{slide}{My title 2}
Some other stufff
\end{slide}
\frame{Dummy frames}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the idea I had but did not know the command \insertsection. But I had to delete -#1 of the code, because it show -L after the section title in the output.

Comment: Because it expects an additional frame title. Again if you had given a MWE we wouldn't have this now, would we?

Comment: No worries, playing with the code that you have shown me I have achieved to get what I wanted. Thank you again.

Comment: This approach will not work if you need `[allowframebreaks]` with manual control in `slide`. What do you think?

Comment: I extended another issue about the answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346485/13173

Answer (score 7):

With the handy `xpatch` package, you can simply add the section to the frametitle. No need to define a new environment and run into all the problems this new environment will cause.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{\insertsection-\insertframetitle}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Sec shun 1}
\frame{Dummy frames}
\begin{frame}{My title 1}
Some stufff
\end{frame}


\section{Sec shun 2}
\begin{frame}{My title 2}
Some other stufff
\end{frame}
\frame{Dummy frames}
\end{document}
```

[image]