# Why this beamer slide about sectioning fails on enumerates?

Tags: beamer, errors, lists

I am trying to use the code from [section title in \frametitle beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94631)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley} 

\newenvironment{slide}[1]
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide]
\frametitle{\insertsection-#1}}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{slide}
\begin{enumerate}
\item lorem
\end{enumerate}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

but get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15     \end{slide}
```

Comment: Consider to add the `fragile` option for such slide wrapper environments

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done. I am testing its effect but cannot really understand. Docs say *fragile every contents is written into an external file and read back. Not a big deal but makes compiling slow* in the thread http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136240/drawbacks-of-using-fragile-frames-in-beamer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of the `slide` environment here *requires* a title an the argument. Thus here `\begin` is being taken as the argument, we have no list starting and `\item` is misplaced (as the error says). You can fix by supplying something

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley} 

% 
\newenvironment{slide}[1]
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide]
\frametitle{\insertsection-#1}}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{slide}{Foo}
\begin{enumerate}
\item lorem
\end{enumerate}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

If the frame title is not required then drop the argument entirely

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley} 

% 
\newenvironment{slide}
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide]
\frametitle{\insertsection}}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{slide}
\begin{enumerate}
\item lorem
\end{enumerate}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? - - You can do `\begin{slide}{}` but it will insert the line `-` which I would not like to have.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 The _entire point_ of the definition of the `slide` environment here is to have a 'forced' frame title. If you don't want one, just stick to the standard `beamer` `frame` environment and add `\frametitle` as required.

Comment: Yes, but if you already have `\section` which forces the title. I just do not want always have the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do without the `newenvironment`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{\insertsection{} -- \insertframetitle}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Sec shun 2}
\begin{frame}{My title 2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item lorem
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```