# How to allowbreak on Beamer Berkeley left-hand-side navbar?

Tags: beamer, navigation

I have too many sections in my presentation such that the left-hand-side navigation bar is full and only shows the first sections in Fig. 2, initial situation in Fig. 1. 
Pseudocode

- clean the left-hand-hand side navigation bar when exceed the threshold and start a new one there when on sufficient page
- this feature occurs with Beamer Berkeley appendix so it is possible also with the main document

Code which problem shown in Fig. 2

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley} 
\logo{\includegraphics{logo.png}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346486/13173
\newenvironment{slide}[1]
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{\insertsection-#1}
}
{\end{frame}}
% fragile only if code
% allowframebreaks not by default 

\begin{document} 
\title{Sensory system. Primary sensory modalities. Cortical modalities. Kinds of sensory disturbances. Spinal cord disorders. Spinal cord transverse and partial lesion. Cauda equina damage.}
\author{Leo}

\section{Cortical modalities}
\begin{slide}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{slide}

\section{Cortical modalities}
\begin{slide}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{slide}

\section{Cortical modalities 2}
\begin{slide}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{slide}

\section{Cortical modalities 3}
\begin{slide}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{slide}

\section{Cortical modalities 4}
\begin{slide}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Situation at the first page, 
Fig. 2 Situation at Section 6 wheere the navbar has not changed, 
Fig. 3 Samcarter's answer output + one `slide` addition but without `\part{}` - fails on sufficient page count

[image]
[image]
[image]

Output: the left-hand-side navigation bar is not refreshed when the amount of sections exceed its capacity on suffcient enough page

### Testing Samcarter's proposal

I include one `slide` before Samcarter's body so I get the wrong output in Fig. 3. 
**Solution**: Eventually correct output by just adding `\part{}` in the place where the new navbar is wanted.

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled. Please make a compilable document that does not rely on files we don't have access to.

Comment: Why do you list the headlines of all the sections in the title? Just leave the title away if you don't use a title slide.

Comment: Well, but by having all the sections in your document, you already get a full list of sections in the sidebar. Plus, it is displayed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually split the sidebar into smaller chunks that fit in the available space using `\part{}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley} 
\logo{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{\insertsection-\insertframetitle}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\title{Sensory system. Primary sensory modalities. Cortical modalities. Kinds of sensory disturbances. Spinal cord disorders. Spinal cord transverse and partial lesion. Cauda equina damage.}
\author{Leo}

\section{Cortical modalities}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\section{Cortical modalities 1}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\section{Cortical modalities 2}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\part{}
\section{Cortical modalities 3}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\section{Cortical modalities 4}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*(don't load `hyperref`, beamer already does this for you)*

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 The solution is independent of your misuse of the `slide` environment - I just don't want to condone `allowframebreaks` as default.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 It is the exact same output with slide.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Yes, place `\part{}` where you want the break points

Comment: I confirm your proposal works only with the addition `\part{}`! - - I think the automatic approach for this is difficult, but manual is a good one.  - - Why do you use `xpatch` package?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 With `xpatch` I add the section name to the framtitle - which is the way you displayed it in your original code.

Comment: I think I do not need it with `slide` approach.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 And I thhink using the `slide` approach is a bad idea (but we already had this conversation some time ago).