# How to adjust text dynamically to one Beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, fontsize, text-manipulation

I tried `\resizebox{\textheight}{!}{}` but not adjusting the content to the page height in the frame. 
I do it manually by `\small{...}`, `\footnotesize{...}` and `\tiny{...}` but it is too cumbersome.

Example slide

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley} 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94632/13173
\newenvironment{slide}[1]
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide,allowframebreaks,fragile]
\frametitle{\insertsection-#1}
}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{slide}{Global burden by World Bank}

\tiny{
Global burden of STIs and their consequences (World Bank)
\begin{itemize}
\item among world’s most common diseases, with an annual incidence exceeded only by diarrheal diseases, malaria, and lower respiratory diseases. 
\item Due to their high \textbf{prevalence}, particularly in developing settings, STIs result in substantial productivity losses for individuals and communities. %, particularly where the majority of the population is under 40 years of age. 
\item In developing countries, STIs are among the leading causes of disability-adjusted life years (DALYs) lost for \textbf{women} of reproductive age. 
\item Every day, 1M \textbf{acquire} a new STI, and more than 340 million new cases of curable STIs occur throughout the world each year. 
Adolescents and young adults have the highest rates of curable STIs -- up to 1 in 20 adolescents develop a new STI each year. 
\item \textbf{Untreated} bacterial STIs in women - PID in 40\% infections, 1/3 in infertility, ...
\item \textbf{Perinatal deaths}. Syphilis - one of most common causes of adverse pregnancy outcomes globally, 1.5M deaths/year. 
\item \textbf{Chronic liver disease and death}. HBV, 1/40 deaths of adults globally per year. 
\item \textbf{Cervical cancer and death}. Most common cause of cancer mortality among African women. About 0.24 M/year mortality in resource poor seettings. 
\item \textbf{Prevention}. Vaccines, .... Antibiotics for many STIs. Antivirals in HIV and HSV-2.  
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Output which is not adjusted to the page size

[image]

OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: size changes do not take an argument remove the braces from 
`\tiny{...}`

Comment: you need to specify a width for line breaking, but then if you scale the box to textheight either it will be too wide and fall off the right hand side of the page, or be too narrow and leave an over-large right margin. Are you sure you want to scale the text?

Comment: why are you using `allowframebreaks` which allows text to run over to the next slide if you want to force it all on to one slide??????

Comment: Using a specified size such as `\small` is definitely the best thing to do here, I can't see it as being "cumbersome" at all, surely in the overall work of preparing a presentation choosing the font size for one slide is negligable.

Comment: as I say above there is no good way as you need to choose a text width for line breaking and after that scaling is not an option. So you need to choose a font at the start such that line breaking to the frame width more or less fills the page vertically.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there any way to prevent allowframebreaks in one slide?

Comment: yes put the text in a minipage for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with all automatic scaling approaches is that it will affect the height and the width equally, so you are surely better of controlling the fontsize manually or **don't put so much text on a single slide**.

Why do you need complete sentences, wouldn't the diseases themselves be enough and all the additional information should be given orally in your talk?

Never give unnecessary frame options as default - this can only cause trouble. Think about the content of your slides and only add such options if necessary, e.g. `allowframebreaks` only for an automatic bibliography and `fragile` only for frames containing code etc.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley} 

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{\insertsection\space-- \insertframetitle}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}[shrink]
\frametitle{Global burden by World Bank}
Global burden of STIs and their consequences (World Bank)
\begin{itemize}
\item among world’s most common diseases, with an annual incidence exceeded only by diarrheal diseases, malaria, and lower respiratory diseases. 
\item Due to their high \textbf{prevalence}, particularly in developing settings, STIs result in substantial productivity losses for individuals and communities. %, particularly where the majority of the population is under 40 years of age. 
\item In developing countries, STIs are among the leading causes of disability-adjusted life years (DALYs) lost for \textbf{women} of reproductive age. 
\item Every day, 1M \textbf{acquire} a new STI, and more than 340 million new cases of curable STIs occur throughout the world each year. 
Adolescents and young adults have the highest rates of curable STIs -- up to 1 in 20 adolescents develop a new STI each year. 
\item \textbf{Untreated} bacterial STIs in women - PID in 40\% infections, 1/3 in infertility, ...
\item \textbf{Perinatal deaths}. Syphilis - one of most common causes of adverse pregnancy outcomes globally, 1.5M deaths/year. 
\item \textbf{Chronic liver disease and death}. HBV, 1/40 deaths of adults globally per year. 
\item \textbf{Cervical cancer and death}. Most common cause of cancer mortality among African women. About 0.24 M/year mortality in resource poor seettings. 
\item \textbf{Prevention}. Vaccines, .... Antibiotics for many STIs. Antivirals in HIV and HSV-2.  
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can you apply `[shrink]` on a single `slide`? I did `\begin{slide}[shrink]{Lorem}` unsuccessfully.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Don't try to wrap frames in new environments. That is the root of all evil and completely unnecessary. (look at your last 3 questions, all problems caused by this)