# Beamer - include subsection in \frametitle but only if subsection exists i.e. not TOC, reference frames etc

Tags: beamer

Following on from [this answer by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346497/273733) in relation to the question `section title in \frametitle beamer`, I have used the provided answer:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{\insertsection-\insertframetitle}{}{}
\makeatother
```

in my main `beamer` document. I have modified it so that instead of `\insertsection` it is `\insertsubsection` as my subsections are more relevant. However, using this is predictably affecting all of my `frame`'s regardless of whether the `\insertsubsection` is empty (such as for TOC pages). My main document currently looks like this (I used `\insertsection\ - \insertframetitle` instead, notice the spaces around the hyphen):

[image]

How can I test for or only include the `\patchcmd`'s effect when there is a subsection present (or via any method/division that works)? I am also including a TOC per section using:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
 \ifnum \value{framenumber}>1
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
   \frametitle{Outline}
   \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
 \else
 \fi
}
```

and references and perhaps a glossary at the end. One possible solution that I can see is to just repatch the `\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle` command before and after slide(s) that I desire or do not desire the the subsection being in the title but perhaps there is a better way that is beyond my knowledge that could be within others reach, hence the question. **I attempted this to save asking a redundant question and it failed like so:**

[image]

using:

```
\newcommand\showSubsec{
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{\insertsubsection\ - \insertframetitle}{}{}
\makeatother
}

\newcommand\hideSubsec{
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertsubsection\ - \insertframetitle}{\insertframetitle}{}{}
\makeatother
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{\insertsubsection\ - \insertframetitle}{}{}
\makeatother

% For TOC at each section
\AtBeginSection[]
{
 \ifnum \value{framenumber}>1
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
   \frametitle{Outline}
   \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
 \else
 \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Introduction
\end{frame}

\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{First slide Title}
    Text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second subsection}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Second slide Title}
    \small
    Text
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusions and Future Work}
\subsection{Conclusions}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Conclusions}
    \centering
    Text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Future Work}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Future Work}
    \centering
    Text
\end{frame}

\section*{Back matter}
\subsection*{References}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
References
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

MWE output:

[image]

Ideally I want the subsection title in the relevant frames but only if the subsection exists, not in TOC/reference/introduction slides etc. If this is not possible then I will revert to not having the subsections in the `\frametitle` but it would be nice if possible please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. test if the subsection counter is > 0:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{%
\ifnum\thesubsection>0
  \insertsubsection\ - 
\fi
\insertframetitle
}{}{}
\makeatother

% For TOC at each section
\AtBeginSection[]
{
 \ifnum \value{framenumber}>1
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
   \frametitle{Outline}
   \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
 \else
 \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Introduction
\end{frame}

\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{First slide Title}
    Text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second subsection}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Second slide Title}
    \small
    Text
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusions and Future Work}
\subsection{Conclusions}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Conclusions}
    \centering
    Text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Future Work}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Future Work}
    \centering
    Text
\end{frame}

\section*{Back matter}
\subsection*{References}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
References
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```