# Understanding why AtBeginEnvironment{frame} does not work in this MWE

Tags: beamer, environments

I'm trying to understand why the hook `AtBeginEnvironment{frame}` does not seem to apply in this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  
% Redéfinition de l'environnement frame
\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
    \frametitle{\thesection - \insertsection}%
    \framesubtitle{\thesubsection - \insertsubsection}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
\begin{document}
 
\section{section n°1}
\subsection{sous-section 1-1}
 
\begin{frame}
Texte du slide.
\end{frame}
 
\end{document}
```

Normally, it should print a title and a subtitle in the frame, but for some reason that I don't understand it does not.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: note your example, as posted here, is necessarily in UTF-8 so `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` needs to be deleted

Comment: frame is not a standard environment but a rather special command.

Comment: So, doing such thing is impossible? Maybe in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the frametitle at the start of the frame environment is too early. As there are people - including pandoc users - who use the extremely annoying syntax `\begin{frame}{frametitle}{framesubtitle}`, beamer needs to jump through a lot of hoops to deal with this complicate syntax. You have to wait with `\frametitle` after beamer is done with this.

Instead of messing with the frame environment, disable beamer's checks for the existence of a frametitle and patch the frametitle to show the section/subsection if the frametitle is empty:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{%
\ifx\insertframetitle\@empty
  \thesection{} - \insertsection
  \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty
  \ifnum\thesubsection>0
    \def\insertframesubtitle{\thesubsection{} - \insertsubsection}
  \fi\fi
\else
  \insertframetitle
\fi
}{}{}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{section 1}
\subsection{sub 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle}
\framesubtitle{framesub}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again SamCarter. This is indeed working a bit better in Pandoc. I'm trying to figure out how to add the current section in the subtitle. Replacing the occurrences of title with subtitle in your snippet does not seems to work... investigating.

Comment: And there is another issue, your snippet add a title on the \titlepage and \sectionpage

Comment: @PolDellaiera Sure it does add them to the title page etc. Your question does not ask to exclude any special frames, so why should an answer exclude them? However you can exclude them as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661314/beamer-include-subsection-in-frametitle-but-only-if-subsection-exists-i-e-no/661329#661329

Comment: Thanks, I will see what I can do with all these information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  
% Redéfinition de l'environnement frame
\let\oldframe\frame
\def\newframe{%
\oldframe\frametitle{\thesection - \insertsection}%
\framesubtitle{\thesubsection - \insertsubsection}%
}
\def\endnewframe{\endframe}

\renewenvironment{frame}{\newframe}{\endnewframe}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
\begin{document}
 
\section{section n°1}
\subsection{sous-section 1-1}
 
\begin{frame}
Texte du slide.
\end{frame}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it works pretty fine in Overleaf.

Sadly, this is failing when using Pandoc to convert a markdown file to beamer. That's extremely weird.

Comment: @PolDellaiera Not weird at all. Pandoc uses the extremly annoying syntax `\begin{frame}{frametitle}{framesub}` to set the frame title and subtitle and by redefining the frame environment you'll loose the ability to use this syntax as well as optional arguments.